# How does Android Market install application?

Tags: android, google-play

This is more like general knowledge to understanding Android Market. So, first and foremost, I am sorry I has to ask here. I search for quite a while and still don't understand it. So, here we go.

As far as my knowledge is concerned, packageInstaller does  install applications on Android. It does ask for user permission before it carries out installation.

So my question is "Does android market use packageInstaller or it does installation by itself?"

If it does not, there are a few things that I am not clear about.

- I am almost certain that permissions are extracted from AndroidManifest.xml file. Before downloading, how does Android Market knows what are permissions required from the app? (My guess is that Android Market Web-end has recorded permissions when apk is uploaded)
- Android Market asks user to agree permissions before it downloads apk. If user agrees and downloads, installation is carried out straight away after downloading (i.e. without launching packageInstaller). How is that possible?
- As a third party application, can any app does the same job as Android Market?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think I can ask to some your questions.
Package installer is not used for installing applications from Android Market - it does installation by itself.

1. I do not know precisely but I think for the first question you are
   right. Android Market knows about the permission that the app
   requires. It also can simply parse the AndroidManifest file of the
   application.
2. This is done with the help of GTalkService. You can read more [here](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2010/06/25/remote-kill-and-install-on-google-android/)
   about it.
3. In general case no. But yes, if your app is signed with the system
   signature.

Comment: Thz u for your answer. Can you elaborate a bit more for your third point?

Comment: As I know components that are required for the installation of applications are protected with signatureOrSystem permission.

Comment: Fair enough. I bumped into this link [http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fe47bc6c72914df0] on google group. It seems no way to install applications on android bypassing PackageInstaller.

Comment: but appbrain did it successfully with their fast web installer. It does the job on the phone with no interaction. @Yury is right this has something to do with the GTalkService. I'm dying to know how they did it, I hope someone can shed some info about this :)

Comment: "GTalkService is actually used during the normal Android Market install process.  Instead of downloading the APK from the Market, clicking ‘Install’ will trigger Google’s servers to push a INSTALL_ASSET message down the GTalkService pipe.  Upon receiving this message, your phone will download and install the APK." I'm not sure but I think to use AppBrain you need to install an application for the market. After this I think AppBrain registers a C2DM service and waits for messages from the server. After this it works like Android market but at the end just call package manager to install package

Comment: @Yury It is not more so. I just blocked GtalkService port (5228). GtalkService is off-line, but market and other Google apps  work fine. It seems, that Google changed the apps installation process